# Database in python - index issue

Tags: python, mysql, database, beautifulsoup

```
for page in range(1, pages + 1):
```

```
def append_organizator(organizator, organizatorzy=[]):
    organizatorzy.append(organizator)
    for i in organizatorzy:
        try:
            query = "INSERT INTO stypendia (organizator) values(%s)"
            values = []
            values.append(organizatorzy.pop())
            cursor.execute(query, values)
            conn.commit()
        except:
            pass

def append_type(rodzaj, rodzaje=[]):
    rodzaje.append(rodzaj)
    for i in rodzaje:
        try:
            query = "INSERT INTO stypendia (rodzaj) values(%s)"
            values = []
            values.append(rodzaje.pop())
            cursor.execute(query, values)
            conn.commit()
        except:
            pass
```

Those are 2 functions that are inserting the data scrapped from website into the database

The program is iterating through all available pages on site. The data that's scrapped is inserted to database.

As you can see on screenshot, the title is inserted 7 times(the amount of pages), then the organizator again 7 times etc...
How can i solve this problem and have everything at same indexes[database ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFwsb.png)

Comment: You're modifying the list `organizatorzy`/`rodzaje` while iterating (with `.pop()`), thats not a good practice. Also, you have mutable object `[]` as a default parameter value, that's bad practice too.

Comment: @AndrejKesely so how am i supposed to add a single item to list without popping it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine the `insert` operations - each insert will create a new row. You should also just use the parameters without the array, they really aren't needed.

This example only handles two parameters (same as your code above). Add additional parameters as needed and adjust the insert statement

```py
    # The organization of this loop assumes the order of returned data is
    # consistent: each "rodzaj" is at the same index as its "organizator"
    # (as the original code assumes)
    organizator = doc.find_all(class_='organizator-title')
    rodzaj = doc.find_all('div', class_='fleft', string="Rodzaj:")
    for i in range(min(len(organizator), len(rodzaj))):
        o = organizator[i].text.strip().replace('\\n', '').replace('\\r', '')
        r = rodzaji].find_next().text.strip().replace('\\n', '').replace('\\r', '')
        append(o, r)


def append(organizator: str, rodzaj: str):
    try:
        query = "INSERT INTO stypendia (organizator, rodzaj) values(%s, %s)"
        values = (organizator, rodzaj)
        cursor.execute(query, values)
        conn.commit()
    except:
        pass
```